# excel vba ping list of computers

Tags: vba, excel, ping

I am working on a project. My goal is, to ping all of the computers from an excel list, but can't figure out why it isn't working. I am quite new at this programming language, and I am sure that I miss out something, because I get the error message: Object required

so here is my code

the main:

```
Sub pingall_Click()
Dim c As Range
c = Target.Name

For Each c In Range("A1:N50")
    If (Left(c, 1) = "C" Or Left(c, 1) = "T") And IsNumeric(Right(c, 6)) And Len(c) = 7 Then
    c = sPing(c)
        If c = "timeout" Then
            MsgBox "timeout"
        ElseIf c < 16 And c > -1 Then
            MsgBox "ok"
        ElseIf c > 15 And c < 51 Then
            MsgBox "not ok"
        ElseIf c > 50 And c < 4000 Then
            MsgBox "big delay"
        Else
            MsgBox "error"

        End If
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

The function:

```
Public Function sPing(sHost) As String

Dim oPing As Object, oRetStatus As Object

Set oPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery _
  ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & sHost & "'")

For Each oRetStatus In oPing
    If IsNull(oRetStatus.StatusCode) Or oRetStatus.StatusCode <> 0 Then
        sPing = "timeout" 'oRetStatus.StatusCode
    Else
        sPing = sPing & vbTab & oRetStatus.ResponseTime & Chr(10)
    End If
Next
End Function
```

I can get the result if I write sPing(""), but I want it to get the name of pc-s that are in the list.
This is just a test version of the script, I am testing it with one pc for now, that is why I use "MsgBox".

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd line inside the `Sub pingall_Click()` subroutine is the one throwing the `Object Required` error. i.e. the following line.

```
c = Target.Name
```

If you comment it out or delete it, it works. (I tried it.)

Also, you should not be assigning the return value from the function `sPing` back to `c`.
Because doing so will overwrite the name of the Server / IP address you have in the cell, since the forloop is looping over 1 cell at a time using the `c` variable.

So instead, assign it back to a new string variable, and then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't belive that was all the problem. Now everything works as I wanted! :-)