# How would I check availability of a service with Visual Basic?

Tags: vba

Currently, I have an application which will open webpages and such by the means of clicking a button. All of that works fine, but what I am really wanting to do is send out a tiny ping every once in a while so people will know if the servers are online or offline before they try to join. I would simply want it to say "Online" or "Offline" below it. How would I constantly check if a server is up?

Here is the code I have so far:

```vb
Public Class MainApp
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Process.Start ("steam://connect/216.52.148.114:2302") ' -Not WORKING
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Process.Start ("WEBSITEURL") ' -WORKS
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Process.Start ("TEAMSPEAK IP") ' -WORKS
    End Sub
End Class
```

It all works fine except connecting to the Arma 3 server through Steam. It does this:

[image: server error screenshot]

Comment: Considering I said "I have an application which will open webpages and such by the means of clicking a button. All of that works fine" that means I have already done most of it.

http://pastebin.com/raw/3b6qQp90

It all works fine except connecting to the Arma 3 server through Steam. It does this:

https://gyazo.com/505fcc78eb66c9b6b62363cb89b4f229

Comment: Didnt seem relevant. None of the other stuff has to do with the problem.

Comment: Here are already some solutions on Stack Overflow allowing to ping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020077/ping-ip-address-with-vba-code-and-return-results-in-excel or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442936/excel-vba-ping-list-of-computers Give them a try.

Comment: Alright, that's not as important...but I am trying to connect to a steam server with the code and it doesnt work, says server is not responding. Why??